# While looping in mysqli prepared statement

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop, mysqli, prepared-statement

Is it possible to do something like we do in normal mysqli queries in prepared statements in while lopping.
For example

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users"*;
$query = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
   echo $row['username'];
   echo $row['name'];
}
```

In prepared statements, it goes like this

```
$fetch_comments = $friend_zone->prepare("SELECT item_poster, comment FROM status_comments WHERE status_id = ? and item_poster = ?");
$fetch_comments->bind_param("is", $status__id, $item_poster);
$fetch_comments->execute();
$fetch_comments->store_result();
$fetch_comments->bind_result($item_poster_fetched, $comment_fetched);
while($fetch_comments->fetch(){
  echo $item_poster;
}
```

What i mean is i want to do the echo like so

```
echo $row['something'];
```

The solution i came up with now is to fetch them using bind result, then put them into an array inside the loop and then `foo['bar'];` or something of that sort.
Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't this work?

```
$fetch_comments = $friend_zone->prepare("SELECT item_poster, comment FROM status_comments       WHERE status_id = ? and item_poster = ?");
$fetch_comments->bind_param("is", $status__id, $item_poster);
$fetch_comments->execute();
$result = $fetch_comments->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    echo $row['something'];

}
```

Comment: im gonna try this out, i thought this way would not work because in the manual the example was different...

Comment: i dont have the mysqlnd driver, so is there any other solution?

Comment: So in this case the $fetch_comments->get_result(); instruction fails... So probabily the solution you originally proposed works good enough...

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You're almost there with your code. You just need to assign the value to $row within the while loop's condition check:</strike>

```
while( $row = $fetch_comments->fetch() ) {
   echo $row['somefield'];
}
```

The data is now bound to the `$item_poster_fetched` variable from what I understand...

```
while($fetch_comments->fetch())
{
    $item_poster_fetched['something'];
}
```

Comment: thanks i was a bit confused as the while loop example in the manual was a tad bit different

Comment: @cillosis `mysqli_stmt::fetch` returns a boolean, please read the question again.

Comment: @xdazz Thanks for pointing that out, I was unaware of that behavior. I guess I've gotten too used to PDO.

Comment: @cillosis i dont think thats how it works, because with bind_result, im binding a variable to one field.
example: item_poster is binded to $item_poster_fetched and
comment is binded to $comment_fetched